# nested function returning outer function

Tags: python, return, global

I have a common pattern that goes like

```
def f(x):
  if x.type == 'Failure':
     # return `x` immediately without doing work
     return x
  else:
  # do stuff with x...
  return x
```

I would like to abstract the *if/else* pattern into a stand alone function. However I want that function, when called from inside `f`, to **return from f** immediately. Else it should just return x to a value **inside f** for further processing. Something like

```
def g(x):
  if x.type == 'Failure':
    global return x
  else:
    return x.value

def f(x):
  x_prime = g(x) # will return from f
                 # if x.type == 'Failure'
  # do some processing...
  return x_prime
```

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible at all, or if there's a quick shortcut for doing it in Python? It's certainly quite possible and relatively easy to put in the logic yourself, such as by returning a tuple from `g` instead of a single value, and using one of the values in the tuple to tell `f` to return immediately or not. That's just one example of how you could do it, but it's not necessarily something built-in in Python.

Comment: @RandomDavis I want to _abstract_ that, so I can use `g` everywhere without changing code that only handles `x.value`. I'm thinking a decorator function could be a neat solution, but I welcome other alternatives. Yes, an actual solution would be better than a plain `yes` or `no`!

Comment: I doubt you can do this, and it seems like a bad idea in the first place. A function should not make assumptions about how the caller will use its result.

Comment: @Barmar Python has mutable global variables. Enough said. Plenty of opportunity for magical behaviour.

Comment: Almost all languages have global variables. Very few have what you want here.

Comment: The only language I can think of where this could be done is Common Lisp, using a macro that expands into a `RETURN` expression. And even then, its behavior would depend on where it's used, because `RETURN` will exit the closest enclosing loop or function.

Comment: In Scheme you could do it with a function that takes a second argument, a continuation to call in the case where you want to do the global return.

Comment: @Barmar, I solved it. Solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `Validation` from [my branch](https://gitlab.com/dmvianna/pycategories/tree/validation) of pycategories:

```
def fromSuccess(fn):
    """
    Decorator function. If the decorated function
    receives Success as input, it uses its value.
    However if it receives Failure, it returns
    the Failure without any processing.
    Arguments:
        fn :: Function
    Returns:
        Function
    """
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        d = kwargs.pop('d')
        if d.type == 'Failure':
            return d
        else:
            kwargs['d'] = d.value
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@fromSuccess
def return_if_failure(d):
    return d * 10

return_if_failure(d = Failure(2)), return_if_failure(d = Success(2))

>>> (Failure(2), 20)
```